# Confused on ssas aggregation design

Tags: ssas

I have read about aggregation design tab in ssas.It is telling we can precalculate the aggregation and it will improve the response time.But when i tried that option,i haven't go thorough any step which is showing what kind of aggregation(eg:sum,avg etc) we have to do.In one of the steps, there is an option of specifying count of rows.So aggregation means only count of rows in table?
Other than this we know,there is one calculated measure option using we can specify sum or avg or etc.This also one kind of aggregation right?

So, Can any one please make it clear about there two?

Thank You in advance.. :)

Comment: In the above,Calculated measure is,'new measure' option above the measure and next to process button.Not from the calculation tab

Comment: Hi,If my question is not clear,my Question is..What will happen if we create aggregation using aggregation design tab in ssas?can any one explain step by step process happening internaly in ssas?

Comment: Aggregations are pre-calculated combinations of dimension members (or hierarchies) and measures. Depending on your storage model, your aggregation design will be pre-calculated and stored when you process the cube. Internally, when a user tries to access data, SSAS will first look at the cache, second at your aggregations and last and your actual data.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for replay.Here "Aggregations are pre-calculated combinations of dimension members (or hierarchies) and measures" means? If i create a new measure attribute,for example avg(salesAmount) on my factSales measure,Whether these value will be precalculated using aggregation design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but the method of aggregation is defined for each measure. See the properties of your measures to know what kind of aggregation method is used.

The estimated row count (of each partition) is used by SSAS to determine the necessary storage space of your aggregation design.